# How to write data into an empty NfcV tag?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I am new to Android and working on an NFC project. I have an empty NfcV tag. I need to write data into the tag and read data from it. Any kind of help is appreciated by me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific IC in the tag. NfcV tags are ISO15693 compliant. The standard defines multiple read and write commands (ReadBlock, ReadMultipleBlocks, WriteBlock, WriteMultipleBlocks), support for all of which is optional. There may also be manufacturer-specific commands for reading and/or writing. So you need to know what commands are supported by your tag.